# Edit Data in Grid Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to edit the Column "Stock". Editing must be done for all rows having a value greater than 5. 
Right now, if it is 10, then it must reduce 1 by 1 until it gets to 5 and then adding back to 10. One it is completed going from 10 to 5 and then back to 10, then it must process next row.

Image of website's screen grid/table is uploaded.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\ABC\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver')
browser.get('https://seller.Mine.com/')
browser.find_element_by_id('Final').click()
browser.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys('mine@gmail.com')
browser.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys('xxxx')
submit = WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='sc-aewfc iesYjz']//span")))
submit.click()
browser.get('https://seller.Mine.com/index.html#dashboard/listings-management?listingState=ACTIVE')
```

[nium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnaKl.jpg)

[Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us5fh.jpg)

Comment: Can you post the HTML or a working link to the page you are automating here? The link is broken, and without the link / HTML, we cannot visualize how to use Selenium to help solve your issue. It would be best if you either posted a working link, or the HTML text for the table containing the element that you are trying to click (in the question body, not a screenshot)

Comment: @christine I have added code as image. The link is not working since its a eCommerce portal after Sign In. If you could see the image that I have just added, it will be helpfull

Comment: I did mention in my previous comment to post the text of the HTML into your question body, not a screenshot. This screenshot also only shows the table headers, it does not show anything about the table rows / editable cells themselves, which is what you need to edit here. This question is still impossible to answer without additional context of the ENTIRE table, not just the table headers. Please just cut and paste the HTML, rather than posting a screenshot.